# How to monitor the creation of Blob in Azure Storage container/subfolders and Trigger a logic app to send email

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

We have Azure storage container with subfolders created dynamically, we want to monitor the creation of blob under this container/subfolders and trigger an email once per day with all the blobs added for the day as an attachment in the email.

What we tried is to create a Logic app with Event Grid Trigger (When a resource event occurs) like below.

[image]

we would like to know if there is way we can collect all the blobs added in a day under the container and get the contents of all those blobs and add it as an attachment and trigger an email at scheduled time once per day.

Any suggestion on

1. how to get all the blobs under a container, sub-folder and store the blobs metadata created as an array?
2. And then how to attach all the blobs created in a single email?
3. How to get the blob name after, "When a resource event occurs" trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a logic app to send email with attachment of all the blobs inside a container that were added a day before the current day.

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "Current_time": {
            "inputs": {},
            "kind": "CurrentTime",
            "runAfter": {
                "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "For_each": {
            "actions": {
                "For_each_2": {
                    "actions": {
                        "Condition": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "name": "attachements",
                                        "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {
                                        "Compose": [
                                            "Succeeded"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                },
                                "Compose": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Get_Blob'))}",
                                        "Name": "@{last(split(items('For_each_2')?['Path'],'/'))}"
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {
                                        "Get_Blob": [
                                            "Succeeded"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "type": "Compose"
                                },
                                "Get_Blob": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "host": {
                                            "connection": {
                                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "method": "get",
                                        "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<StorageAccountName/connection>'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_2')?['Path']))}/content",
                                        "queries": {
                                            "inferContentType": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "ApiConnection"
                                }
                            },
                            "expression": {
                                "and": [
                                    {
                                        "greater": [
                                            "@items('For_each_2')?['LastModified']",
                                            "@addDays(body('Current_time'),-1)"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "If"
                        }
                    },
                    "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)_3')?['value']",
                    "runAfter": {
                        "Lists_blobs_(V2)_3": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "Foreach"
                },
                "Lists_blobs_(V2)_3": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "host": {
                            "connection": {
                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                            }
                        },
                        "method": "get",
                        "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<storageaccount connection>'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Path']))}",
                        "queries": {
                            "nextPageMarker": "",
                            "useFlatListing": false
                        }
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "ApiConnection"
                }
            },
            "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
            "runAfter": {
                "Current_time": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Foreach"
        },
        "Initialize_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "attachements",
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<storageaccount connection>'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmY2FyYm9uYmxh='))}",
                "queries": {
                    "nextPageMarker": "",
                    "useFlatListing": false
                }
            },
            "metadata": {
                "JTJmY2FyYm9uYmxh=": "/<containerName>"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        },
        "Send_an_email_(V2)_3": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "Attachments": "@variables('attachements')",
                    "Body": "<p>body</p>",
                    "Subject": "Subject",
                    "To": "Email"
                },
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "post",
                "path": "/v2/Mail"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "For_each": [
                    "Succeeded",
                    "Failed",
                    "Skipped",
                    "TimedOut"
                ]
            },
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": {},
            "type": "Object"
        }
    },
    "triggers": {
        "Recurrence": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "schedule": {
                    "hours": [
                        "9"
                    ],
                    "minutes": [
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "timeZone": "Standard Time"
            },
            "type": "Recurrence"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                "connectionName": "azureblob",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/<location>/managedApis/azureblob"
            },
            "office365": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365-1",
                "connectionName": "office365",
                "id": "/subscriptions/subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/<location>/managedApis/office365"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above requirements, we have created a logic app using timer to list & get the content of all the blob that were created on a particular day & will send an email with the content of the blob as an attachment. using the below work flow code you make the changes as per your business requirement.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Attach": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Arraytoattach",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Blob_Name": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Count",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": "@length(variables('Arraytoattach'))"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose_2": {
                        "inputs": "@items('For_each')?['LastModified']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Compose_3": {
                        "inputs": "@formatDateTime(outputs('Compose_2'),'yyyy-MM-dd')",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Arraytoattach",
                                    "value": {
                                        "ContentBytes": "@body('Get_blob_content_(V2)_2')?['$content']",
                                        "Name": "@items('For_each')?['Name']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)_2": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            },
                            "Get_blob_content_(V2)_2": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('stacklogictest'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['Path']))}/content",
                                    "queries": {
                                        "inferContentType": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@outputs('Compose_3')",
                                        "@formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose_3": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Attach": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('stacklogictest'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmdGVzdDEyMw=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmdGVzdDEyMw==": "/test123"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Attachments": "@variables('Arraytoattach')",
                        "Body": "<p>Total Number of blob created today : @{variables('Count')}</p>",
                        "Subject": "Blob created Today",
                        "To": "<**ReciepientMailAddress**>"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Blob_Name": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "startTime": "2021-07-15T04:00:00Z"
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroups>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/southindia/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroups>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/southindia/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 1. how to get all the blobs under a container, sub-folder and store the blobs metadata created as an array?

Ans: Using the Event Grid you can add all the blob under a particular container to a single array because event grid triggers the logic app when a new blob is added.

> 2. And then how to attach all the blobs created in a single email?

Ans: Due to outlook restrictions, we cannot sent or attach the data which excceds more than 25 MB.

> 3.How to get the blob name after, "When a resource event occurs" trigger?

Ans : As shown in the below image initialize a string variable and add it to the next of event grid event and add the below experssion to get the blob name from the event grid output
first(split(last(split(string(triggerBody()),'/blobs/')),'","event'))

[image]

The above logic app will fail if the content type of the blob is text you need make  the changes accordingly based on requirement.

Here is the sample output of the above logic app
[image]